# Is it possible to publish a package with an ambient module declaration?

Tags: typescript, module, declaration, type-declaration, ambient

I have a package with tons of generated modules that all export the same type (eg. icon library).

I want to avoid creating a `.d.ts` file for each module as they would all be the same.

Instead, I would like to create an `index.d.ts` file at the root of the package with something like this:

```
// pkg-with-many-assets/index.d.ts

declare module 'pkg-with-many-assets/*' {
    const svgPath: string;
    export default svgPath;
}
```

I'm finding that this doesn't register with consuming apps. However, this works when I place the file within the consuming app.

Is it possible to create a package with an ambient module declaration?

---

Edit:
Seems this is actually possible because [@types/simple-icons](https://unpkg.com/browse/@types/simple-icons@5.8.0/index.d.ts) does it. However, if I were to copy and paste the `@types/simple-icons/index.d.ts` file to `simple-icons/index.d.ts` in my `node_modules` directory, it no longer works.

Perhaps the issue is with TypeScript not reading the `index.d.ts` file at the root of the `simple-icons` package (despite the `"types": "index.d.ts"` specification in `package.json`).

I managed to get the above to work by specifying the package name in `tsconfig.json` `compilerOptions.types`, but obviously I would like this detection to be automatic without manual configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#:%7E:text=If%20types%20is%20specified%2C%20only%20packages%20listed%20will%20be%20included%20in%20the%20global%20scope.%20For%20instance%3A), that

> If types is specified, only packages listed will be included in the
> global scope.

So, It's possible that you have types already specified which is stopping the automatic discovery of your package @types. Try removing the compilerOptions.types completely

Comment: That was the state I was in initially but doesn't work. (Btw, custom package so no @types/* via DefinitelyTyped.)